# Enable Internal relation in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my new Synology WebServer I have installed mariadb with phpMyAdmin but I can't set internal relation in my table.

How can enable this function?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `InnoDB` engine, rather than `MyISAM`,
otherwise you won't be able to add the relationship.

Comment: On phpMyAdmin, you can change the engine by going to the selected table, and open the `Operation` tab. Storage engine can be found on `Table options` section.

Comment: in xampp I am able to use InnoDB and internal relation.
Internal relation are very comfortable when I must add data from phpmyadmin during developing

Comment: Can you reconfirm that your tables are all InnoDB on Synology?

Comment: Can you run the following query? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have%'; ` and what is the result of the query on `have_innodb`?

Comment: I haven't this variable

Comment: Is the tab `Relation View` in table `Structure` exist? If yes, either one of the tables must have UNSIGNED integer where the other one hasn't. Please check.

Comment: The relation view table exist!.
The same database into phpmyadmin under xampp have internal relation and under synology haven't it.
Exist there some configuration unknow to me